Encountered Whitelabel Error Page when accessing http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
I am learning how to use Swagger 3 in Spring Boot 3.25. I can access http://localhost:8080/rad and test data is available.
My dependencies
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

My application
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOpenApi
public class appserver3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(appserver3.class,args);
    }
}

My config
@Configuration
public class swagger_config {

    @Bean
    public Docket apiconfig(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(ApiOperation.class))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
    private ApiInfo apiInfo(){
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Fingers")
                .description("fingers")
                .contact(new Contact("1", "2", "3"))
                .version("1.0")
                .build();
    }
}



my application.yml
Spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher

How do I solve this?

Check your log.

As you mentioned you're using Swagger 3 which is basically OpenApi 3.0 so you have to modify your swagger_config class because you're using Swagger 2.0 config which is not compatible with Swagger 3.
Docket and ApiInfo is not supporting any more in Swagger 3.
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>

You can refer these links for more details
Spring Rest OpenApi
Another implementation link

Thank you very much！That explained a lot！
